Github Apps: Resource not accessible by integration
I came across a few other posts describing the same issue, but none of them had a solution, so providing some additional context to my predicament.
Github shows three levels of apps: Oauth Apps, Authorized Github Apps and Installed Github Apps. My goal is to create a new blob and commit this in a given branch.
While using the Access token for the OAuth app, the API requests always work.
--header 'Authorization: Bearer gho_<redacted>' \
--header 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "content": "Content of the blob",
  "encoding": "utf-8"
}'

The access token generated per user for the Authorized Github App work for some repos but not for all:
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ghu_<readcted>' \
--header 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "content": "Content of the blob",
  "encoding": "utf-8"
}'

And most importantly, the installation access token for the Github App raises 403 error:
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ghs_<redacted>' \
--header 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "content": "Content of the blob",
  "encoding": "utf-8"
}'

{
    "message": "Resource not accessible by integration",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/git/blobs#create-a-blob",
    "status": "403"
}

I've checked the Github App permissions multiple times and yes, it has the content permission that is needed for Blob creation. Here are the permissions that the app has:
"permissions": {
      "actions": "write",
      "administration": "write",
      "checks": "write",
      "contents": "write",
      "deployments": "write",
      "environments": "read",
      "issues": "write",
      "metadata": "read",
      "pull_requests": "write",
      "repository_hooks": "write",
      "statuses": "write",
      "workflows": "write"
    }

The Blob creation API mentions that both GitHub App user access tokens and GitHub App installation access tokens will work, but I'm getting 403 errors for both of these.

Am I missing something? How can I address this issue for Installed Github Apps if I want to provide fine-grained access to the end-user?

Does the App itself have required permissions? See Developer Settings
What do you have for the Repository Permissions / Contents?

If installation is correct, then all that is required is to obtain a correct access token. Make sure that JWT has not expired:
jwt=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9......

install_id=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $jwt"  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/app/installations | jq -r ".[0].id")

curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $jwt"  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/app/installations/$install_id/access_tokens -d '' | jq -r .token


Yes, it does. The snippet I sent is of the webhook event from the App installation. It has 12 repo permissions including Contents, Pull Requests, etc.

And the app installed into an account or org for all repos or at least for the repos you are modifying?

Yes, I have installed it in my personal account for all repos and the repo I'm trying to access is public as well
